# Expecting an image or graphics instead of -Image-

Tags: image-processing, scripting

Here's a snippet of my notebook. When run with the frontend, the code runs fine with no problem at all. However, when I save the notebook as .m file and run it using "Mathkernel -noprompt -script notebook.m," the ImageSubtract command throws the error " Expecting an image or graphics instead of -Image-." Any help is appreciated.

```
Print["Processing images..."];
atomImageFile = 
  imagesDirectory <> imageTime <> atomImageSuffix <> imageFormat;
noAtomImageFile = 
  imagesDirectory <> imageTime <> noAtomImageSuffix <> imageFormat;
backgroundImageFile = 
  imagesDirectory <> backgroundImageFileName <> imageFormat;
backgroundImage = Image[Import[backgroundImageFile, "PNG"]];
atomImage = Image[Import[atomImageFile, "PNG"]];
noAtomImage = Image[Import[noAtomImageFile, "PNG"]];
ImageSubtract[atomImage, backgroundImage];

Print["Done."];
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Not able to try it now, but please try assigning `xx = ImageSubtract[...];`.Thanks

Comment: Still giving me the same error @belisarius

Comment: What are FullForm[atomImage] and FullForm[noAtomImage]?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is to convert all images to ImageData for calculation. When the calculation is finished, Export the result image to a file. Here's the code that works.

```
atomImageFile = 
  imagesDirectory <> imageTime <> atomImageSuffix <> imageFormat;
noAtomImageFile = 
  imagesDirectory <> imageTime <> noAtomImageSuffix <> imageFormat;
backgroundImageFile = 
  imagesDirectory <> backgroundImageFileName <> imageFormat;
backgroundImage = 
  ImageData[
   ColorConvert[Image[Import[backgroundImageFile, "PNG"]], 
    "Grayscale"]];
atomImage = 
  ImageData[
   ColorConvert[Image[Import[atomImageFile, "PNG"]], "Grayscale"]];
subtractImage = atomImage - backgroundImage;
subtractImage = Image[subtractImage];
Export[atomImageFile, subtractImage, "TIFF"];
```